# Only leave duplicated rows in a dataframe, with R

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tn1 | a | b |
| tn1 | a | c |
| tn2 | d | b |
| tn3 | a | b |

And I want to leave only those rows that are duplicated for col1 & col2, keeping BOTH rows:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tn1 | a | b |
| tn1 | a | c |

I've been trying to do this by using unique() or distinct() or anti_join() but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** To address @r2evans concerns (see comments):

```
df[duplicated(df[,c("col1","col2")]) | duplicated(df[,c("col1","col2")], fromLast=TRUE),]

OR: 

df[ave(rep(0, nrow(df)), df[,c("col1","col2")], FUN = length) > 1,]
```

Base R:

```
df[df$col1 %in% df$col1[duplicated(df$col1)],]
```

```
  col1 col2 col3
1  tn1    a    b
2  tn1    a    c
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account `col2`?

Comment: For this example it is enough to check for col1. Alternatively we must check for all columns to be sure. And it seems that OP looked for such a solution.

Comment: The sample data provided is insufficient. Using a slightly modified `df <- structure(list(col1 = c("tn1", "tn1", "tn1", "tn2", "tn3"), col2 = c("a", "a", "Q", "d", "a"), col3 = c("b", "c", "Q", "b", "b")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))` (just one extra `"tn1"` row) and the OP *"duplicated for col1 & col2"*, your answer returns three rows. I suggest instead `df[duplicated(df[,c("col1","col2")]) | duplicated(df[,c("col1","col2")], fromLast=TRUE),]`, two rows only. Another: `df[ave(rep(0, nrow(df)), df[,c("col1","col2")], FUN = length) > 1,]`.

Answer (score 1):

With [vctrs](https://vctrs.r-lib.org/):

```r
library(tibble)
library(vctrs)

df <- tribble(
  ~col1, ~col2, ~col3,
  "tn1",   "a",   "b",
  "tn1",   "a",   "c",
  "tn2",   "d",   "b",
  "tn3",   "a",   "b"
)

cols <- df[c("col1", "col2")]

dups <- vec_duplicate_detect(cols)
dups
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

df[dups,]
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   col1  col2  col3 
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 tn1   a     b    
#> 2 tn1   a     c
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-27 with [reprex v2.0.2.9000](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Found this and worked

df  %>% group_by(col1) %>% filter((duplicated(col2) | duplicated(col2, fromLast = T)))